# logout facility in Angular 5+ application when using Windows authentication

Tags: angular, active-directory, windows-authentication, angular5, angular-http-interceptors

I have an angular5 application which is secured using Windows Active directory. I use the typical approach of creating an interceptor which adds WinCredentials: true to the request like the following:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpEvent } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class WinAuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor() { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        req = req.clone({
            withCredentials: true
        });
        return next.handle(req);
    }
}
```

So far so good. This works pretty well and I call the user controller on server side and get the user information and store it in my localstorage. One thing which I am struggling with right now is, how can I logout a user and force him/her to re-enter the credentials again? Currently I have the following signout() method which doesn't accomplish the login prompt:

```
public signOut(): void {
    this.userService.removeUser();
    document.execCommand('ClearAuthenticationCache', false);
}
```

The line

```
this.userService.removeUser()
```

doesn't do anything extraordinary. It only clears the local storage and sets the currentUser to null.

The line

```
document.execCommand('ClearAuthenticationCache', false)
```

also did not come to my rescue to prompt the login-page again [Not in Internet Explorer or any other browser].

Even if I close the browser and open it again when I run the application, all requests are authenticated. How can I achieve the logout facility? I could not find any Angular 4,5 application performing logout() when using Windows Authentication. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Hey, this is not an answer but I have a different problem. I want to get the user information after the user successfully authenticates using windows authentication. Where is the user object that you have mentioned sending to the web api?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: No solution found, also I narrowed it down to this question: How would you instruct the browser to show its login-window and no "concrete answer" came through. That means I could not even find the command or script which would "for sure" show the login window [ sometimes they worked, sometimes they did not ].